# React-Navigation and Webview navigation

Tags: react-native, webview, react-navigation

I'm using React-navigation and have 3 tabs, one of the tabs renders a webpage using Webview. On this screen if a user swipes left or presses back i want them to go back within the Webview website instead of going to the previous Tab.

I am updating the state within the webview component onNavigationStateChange but not sure how to override the React-navigation swipe.

Answer (score 0):

[TabNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) let's you choose the behavior of your tabs defining the `TabNavigatorConfig`.

In your case, if you want the `TabNavigator` not to listen to swipes, you got to declare `swipeEnabled` to `false`:

```
const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  Screen1: {
    screen: screen1,
  },
  Screen2: {
    screen: screen2,
  },
}, {
  swipeEnabled: false,
});
```

That way your tabs won't conflict with your webview.

Hope it helps !